# Why SBT is publishing a JAR which is skipped?

Tags: scala, sbt

Need help to understand why SBT would try to publish a JAR which is already skipped? And how to fix this issue?
Like in the following build log, publishing of `my-service_2.13-0.45.13-tests.jar` was skipped but still the `sbt publish` shows `[error] java.io.IOException` in putting it on artifactory.

```
[warn] Skipping publication of already published artifact: my-service_2.13-0.45.13-tests.jar
[warn] Skipping publication of already published artifact: my-service_2.13-0.45.13-sources.jar
[warn] Skipping publication of already published artifact: my-service_2.13-0.45.13.pom
[warn] Skipping publication of already published artifact: my-service_2.13-0.45.13-it.jar
[warn] Skipping publication of already published artifact: my-service_2.13-0.45.13.jar
[error] java.io.IOException: PUT operation failed because the destination file exists and overwriting is disabled:
[error]     source     : /home/my-system/my-service/target/scala-2.13/my-service_2.13-0.45.13-tests.jar
[error]     destination: https://my-artifactory.com/artifactory/com/my-org/my-service_2.13/0.45.13/my-service_2.13-0.45.13-tests.jar
[error] If you have a staging repository that has failed, drop it and start over.
[error] Otherwise fix the double publishing, or relax the setting as follows:
[error]     publishConfiguration := publishConfiguration.value.withOverwrite(true)
[error]     publishLocalConfiguration := publishLocalConfiguration.value.withOverwrite(true)
```

I am using SBT 1.3.13 with Scala 2.13.3

Comment: Can you share your `build.sbt`? Also I'm not sure why you use `publish` if you know that the artifacts are already published

Comment: if you do not want to publish some of your SBT modules, you can use special setting in the module settings( publishArtifact := false )

Comment: @GaëlJ - the artifacts are not published till the time `sbt publish` command is used. However, the question is, if the first statement says `Skipping publication...`, then why SBT is throwing error?